# Oracle database backup and restore options

Tags: oracle

We have one requirement that export data from two different source Oracle DBs and restore the data to another two different target Oracle DBs to do data comparison.  We care about the datafiles in these two source Oracle DBs.

The Oracle db are 11.2 RAC. Can we use Oracle data dump tools such like impdp and expdp to meet the above requirement? Or is there any limitation to use data dump tools for the above requirement?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Data pump export & import are just fine for moving data around; I don't know of any limitation in what you described.

Answer (score 0):

data pump impdp and expdp will be fine. consider using network link data pump to save time and effort.